# Preferable format for list of holidays

Tags: user-expectation, lists, user-centered-design

Is the format shown below preferable for showing a list of holidays to a user?
[image: screenshot of current format]

I was wondering if the name of the Holiday should be displayed first rather the date

Comment: You really should do some user testing to figure it out, A/B testing could be quite suitable for this scenario. We can't really give you any concrete advises on what people prefer, only options.

Comment: It depends on the purpose of this list: if it's a 'look up' for public holidays then the name of the holiday should go first, if it's a 'look up' for what dates are public holidays then the dates should go first. Check with your audience - find out how they want to use it.

Comment: who is your user?

Comment: I suggest to put them under separate headings for each month, makes it easier to scan and locate the desired month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could go two ways, depending on **why** your user needs your list.
Is this a reference for specific holidays only? Or a list of everything happening in the year?

If the former, name of holiday first, then date. Why? Because people are specifically looking for specific holidays. They are scanning for the holiday name because they don't know when the holiday is.

If the latter, I'd say date first, then name of holiday. Preferably with the weekday in between. This is because your users are then likely to look for an overview and need to see how holidays are related to one another. For example, if they are looking to vacation in april, they will look to 'combo' multiple holidays to minimize days to take off. Examples: Good Friday and Easter. This is also where weekdays become more important than the actual name of the holiday.

The format you listed is very appropriate for this, but be mindful that if you don't shorten dates (like 29th september, 30th september) you'll put a huge empty space in between the date and the weekday. This is very difficult to read and to scan. Consider using dates like Jan, Feb, Mar., Apr. etc.

Holidays spanning multiple days should be separated into specific entries. It causes more mental load to have to ungroup them mentally, than see multiple entries listed below one another. You'll also not run into issues when a holiday (like Easter or Christmas) spans multiple days but each day has a distinct name.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is a company's employee, my suggestion would be to keep the date of the holiday in the beginning, as you have it now. The user task would be to find if they have a day off on a particular date, but maybe not so much caring for the reason of the holiday.

I don't see the need to write down the number of holidays since it is clear from the first column. Maybe an idea would be to keep one holiday per row, for consistency purposes.